# org.obolibrary.oboformat.parser.OBOFormatParser warn WARNING: LINE: 901 Expected white space at pos: 6 LINE: </rdf:RDF>

Tags: java, parsing, ontology, owl-api

I am using a java project to load an ontology from a file (`dbpedia_2016-10.owl`), add some axioms to this ontology then write to `.owl` file as a new ontology. Later on in my project, I load the new ontology using `loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(new File("DBpedia_modified.owl"))` from `OWLOntology` and I get this warning in multiple lines: I noticed that the parser is not happy at `pos 5` or `pos 6`, which correponds to the character `:`:

```
Jan 04, 2020 12:57:49 PM org.obolibrary.oboformat.parser.OBOFormatParser warn
WARNING: LINE: 84  Expected white space at pos: 5  LINE:
<owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/MusicGenre"/>
Jan 04, 2020 12:57:49 PM org.obolibrary.oboformat.parser.OBOFormatParser warn
WARNING: LINE: 85  Expected white space at pos: 6  LINE:
</owl:Restriction>
```

As I am quite new to this area, I don't undestand why the parser is expecting a *white space* instead of `:`; my question is how serious the warning is? and how can I fix it? I googled it but I didn't find a proper response.

Thank you in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore this warning. Your file is in an RDF format, and the warning is from the OBO parser.

If you do not specify which format the ontology uses, OWLAPI will try all available parsers until it finds one that accepts the ontology. The OBO parser is refusing to parse the ontology (correctly), and it is also issuing warnings, which is more than it should do since at that point it should already have thrown an exception.

Edit: to avoid using the OBO parser, you can select the format that should be used:

```
manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(
        new FileDocumentSource(file, new RDFXMLDocumentFormat()));
```

This will try only one parser (I'm guessing the format of your file is RDF/XML).

Comment: Any way to "hide" this warning?

Comment: It's being logged through slf4j so you could configure your logging system to output only errors for the obo package.

Comment: I don't think I am using sel4j for loggin, at least not directly; I hma having a little trouble where to configure the logging system (I am using Eclipse), I would appreciate your guidance very much!

Comment: OWLAPI uses slf4j, and, given that you're seeing logging, there must be a slf4j implementation in your classpath. I can't tell exactly which one, and the configuration differs from one to the other. If you check your classpath, you'll find slf4j-api and at least one other jar with slf4j in the name. Knowing the name of that jar would tell us what configuration it accepts.

Comment: Yes, I can see in my _Maven Dependicies_ that there are `self4j-api-1.7.10.jar` and `jcl-over-sel4j-1.7.7.jar`. For the edit in your answer, I got `The constructor FileDocumentSource(File, RDFXMLDocumentFormat) is undefined`. It seems the constructor accepts only one argument, which is `File` type.

Comment: JCL is Jakarta Commons Logging, so you can follow the instructions about how to configure JCL to remove logging for OBO. Unfortunately I don't have any experience with this logging library so I can't suggest much.

Comment: As for `FileDocumentSource`, which OWLAPI version are you using? Both version 4 and version 5 have a constructor that will accept a format argument.

Comment: I am using the version 3.4.10

Comment: If you can change that, I would strongly recommend it. 3.4.10 is six years old and the 3.x series is not actively developed any longer. 5.1.12 and 4.5.14 are the most recent releases for series 5 and 4.

Comment: I agree with you it is better to use more recent versions, but the project I am working on is bounded by the version 3.